# Devices are not registered in azure push notification hub in xamarin forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to register device token with tag in azure push notification hub in development mode but in azure portal it shows 0 active devices registered, when I check with notification hub it will show one registration is occur.

Here is my sample code:

App delegate:

```
      var deviceTokenDes = deviceToken.Description;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceTokenDes))
        {
            deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Trim('<');
            deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Trim('>');
            deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Replace(" ", "");

            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Trim('<');
            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Trim('>');
            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Replace(" ", "");
        }

        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(myapp.ListenConnectionString, myapp.NotificationHubName);
```

Login view model:

```
   var tags = new List<string> { userId };

        AppDelegate.Hub?.UnregisterAllAsync(AppDelegate.DeviceToken, error =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error);
            }

            AppDelegate.Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(AppDelegate.DeviceToken, new NSSet(tags.ToArray()), errorCallback =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                }
            });
```

I have registered device token with tag after user successfully login in to the application. Can you please suggest idea on.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is all we do in our AppDelegate class.

```
public override async void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            bool ShouldComplete = true;

            // Validate if we have already got a registration
            try
            {
                string validation = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("InitialTagRegistration");
                if (validation.Contains("Completed"))
                {
                    ShouldComplete = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception genEx)
            {
                ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + genEx.Message + " | Source: " + genEx);
            }

            Hub = new SBNotificationHub(ConfigurableSettings.NotificationHubConnectionString, ConfigurableSettings.NotificationHubPathName);

            ApplicationState.SetValue("NotificationHub", Hub);

            // Get previous device token
            NSData oldDeviceToken = await ApplicationSettings.RetrieveDeviceToken();

            // If the token has changed unregister the old token and save the new token to UserDefaults.
            if (oldDeviceToken != null)
            {
                if (oldDeviceToken.ToString() != deviceToken.ToString())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(oldDeviceToken, (error) =>
                        {
                            //check for errors in unregistration process.
                            if (error != null)
                            {
                                ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + error + " | Source: " + "Unregistering old device token against the notification hub.");
                                //exit out of the code here because we can't keep our hub clean without being able to remove the device from our registration list.
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ShouldComplete = true;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception genEx)
                    {
                        ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + genEx.Message + " | Source: " + genEx + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Store current device token 
                bool res = await ApplicationSettings.CacheDeviceToken(deviceToken);
            }

            // Check if we need to perform our initial registrations

            if (ShouldComplete)
            {
                NSSet RegisteredTags = await ApplicationSettings.RetrieveUserTags();

                if (RegisteredTags == null)
                {
                    RegisteredTags = new NSSet("AppleDevice");
                }

                //Register the device against the notification hub keeping the details accurate at all times.
                Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, RegisteredTags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + errorCallback + " | Source: " + "Registering device token against the notification hub.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (deviceToken != null)
                        {
                            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("Completed", "InitialTagRegistration");
                            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The long and short of it is that you don't need to do anything to the device token before passing it up to the azure notification hub. That's what solved the problem for us, ours has been running in an active application for months now without any issues. Hope this helps.

EDIT: in order to update the tags when a user logs in, we store the device token for use later on, and when the user logs in we use the following method in a seperate class to facilitate updating the tags:

```
    public static async Task<bool> UpdateTags(StaffProfile user)
    {
        //Get the instance of the Notification hub
        SBNotificationHub UpdateHub = new SBNotificationHub(ConfigurableSettings.NotificationHubConnectionString, ConfigurableSettings.NotificationHubPathName);
    //Grab the current device token that was stored during the start up process.
    NSData CurrentDeviceToken = await ApplicationSettings.RetrieveDeviceToken();

    //Get and create the tags we want to use.

    string EmailTag = string.Empty;
    string StoreTag = string.Empty;
    string OrganisationTag = "AppleDevice:OrgTag";
    string GenericTag = "AppleDevice:StaffTag";

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
    {
        EmailTag = user.Email;
        //Remove unwanted spaces and symbols.
        EmailTag = EmailTag.Replace(" ", "");
        EmailTag = string.Format("AppleDevice:{0}", EmailTag);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Store?.Name))
    {
        StoreTag = user.Store.Name;
        //Remove unwanted space.
        StoreTag = StoreTag.Replace(" ", "");
        StoreTag = string.Format("AppleDevice:{0}", StoreTag);
    }

    //Create array of strings to the currently fixed size of 3 items.
    NSString[] TagArray = new NSString[4];

    //Only add in the tags that contain data.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailTag)) { TagArray[0] = (NSString)EmailTag; }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StoreTag)) { TagArray[1] = (NSString)StoreTag; }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrganisationTag)) { TagArray[2] = (NSString)OrganisationTag; }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GenericTag)) { TagArray[3] = (NSString)GenericTag; }

    NSSet tags = new NSSet(TagArray);

    // Store our tags into settings
    ApplicationSettings.CacheUserTags(tags);

    try
    {
        if (CurrentDeviceToken == null)
        {
            ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: Device token is empty." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateHub.RegisterNativeAsync(CurrentDeviceToken, tags, (error) =>
            {
                //check for errors in unregistration process.
                if (error != null)
                {
                    ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + error + " | Source: " + "Registering against hub with new tags." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);

                    // Lets do this so that we can force the initial registration to take place again.
                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("Failed", "InitialTagRegistration");
                    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
                }
                else
                {
                    ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[INFORMATION] - Message: Successful Registration - Source: Registering against hub with new tags." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception genEx)
    {
        ApplicationLog.AppendFile(DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  :  " + "[PNS EXCEPTION] - Exception has been hit! - Message: " + genEx.Message + " | Source: " + genEx + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    return await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Digitalsa1nt. In my application I want to set userId be the 'tag'. So user when logged in to the application only we can get userId but the above you can write in app delegate, These code executed before login in to the application. How can I implement this code after user login in to the application.

Comment: So the above is what we use to do an initial registeration for 'Device' specific notifications where we only care about a user having our app installed (So generic notifications about events, etc.), When a user logs in, we have a seperate class that uses the devicetoken we recieved above, and re-registers the device using the new tags.

Comment: How can we re-register the device using new tag. As we fallow same code or need to modify the code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Digitalsa1nt. I will try with the fallowing code and I will send the comment if I have face any problem.

Comment: I have one doubt, If we register device token without tag in app delegate and after user login in to the application we can re-register the device token with tag without un registering previously registered device token in app delegate, Is push notifications are working fine?

Comment: Yep, you don't need tags to register a device, so it stands to reason that you don't need tags to unregister or re-register a device against the notification hub. =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151864/discussion-between-deepak-and-digitalsa1nt).

Comment: Hi, I have tried with fallowing code but i didn't receive any notification. At first time when i send test notification in azure notification hub it will shows one success but didn't receive notification, after second time onward it shows 0 passed and 0 failed.

Comment: that's likely because it's removing the registration, have you made sure your passing the devicetoken up 'as is' without splitting or removing characters.

Comment: yep, I have customized the device token using fallowing code. 
 deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Trim('<');
            deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Trim('>');
            deviceTokenDes = deviceTokenDes.Replace(" ", "");

            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Trim('<');
            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Trim('>');
            DeviceToken = deviceTokenDes.Replace(" ", "");

Comment: I have register device token in fallowing format: 815cbc9c4b2f8fd8e0bdc85cbd957d8aa1d162893daf474d9a8c2090299c212a

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried with fallowing code but i didn't receive any notification. At first time when i send test notification in azure notification hub it will shows one success but didn't receive notification, after second time onward it shows 0 passed and 0 failed.

According to your description, I would recommend you could communicate with APNs directly to check whether you could get the error response to narrow this issue. Here are some useful tutorials, you could refer to them and troubleshoot your issue as follows:

- Official documentation:[Communicating with APNs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1)
- [Knuff](https://github.com/KnuffApp/Knuff), a debug application for Apple Push Notification Service (APNs)
- [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp), a server-side library for sending notification to iOS/OSX (APNS), Android/Chrome (GCM), Windows/Windows Phone, Amazon (ADM) and Blackberry devices. For how to configure and send Apple Push Notifications, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp).